# Full calendar rendering elements multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to add span element before the fc-center class of full calendar so I need to display the month in that span that I want to add, in the eventAfterAllRender i wrote this code

```
var titleHead = new Date( $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate') );
var month_int = titleHead.getMonth();
$(".fc-center").before('<label>' + month_int + '</label>')
```

and each time I press the prev button or the next button it renders the span again, so if I change the view five times, it renders 5 spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better way to get the same effect, using the built-in date formatting options:

```
views: {
    month: { titleFormat: 'M - MMMM YYYY' },
    week: { titleFormat: 'M - MMM D YYYY'},
    day: { titleFormat: 'M - MMM D YYYY'}
},
```

This adds the month number to the start of the displayed date in each of the regular view types.

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/75/ for a working example.

You can remove the other code you wrote in eventAfterAllRender (as shown in the question).

Also see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/titleFormat/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/ for more information on the syntax above. Also see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/ to understand what the formatting tokens do.

---

P.S. It's worth noting that your previous attempt had a number of issues, beyond what you mentioned in the question:

1) It renders multiple times, as mentioned, because you simply kept appending more labels without checking whether there was one already there. eventAfterAllRender runs whenever events are refreshed, which is done automatically when the view or date changes

2) fullCalendar's getDate method (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/) returns a momentJS object, from which you can directly get the current month (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/), so there's absolutely no reason to then turn it into a JS Date object, this was just wasted effort.

3) It fetched the wrong month for display purposes - months in the JS Date objects are zero-based, so for example in December it would display 11 instead of 12. You'd have needed to add 1 to any value you retrieved.

4) It's badly aligned against the date and looks ridiculous. You can use .prepend() to insert it inside the .fc-center element, then it's at the same height.

If you still wanted to implement something like this, in case you want to add other content to the title bar which isn't the month, then you should move your code outside the calendar config, to just after you declare fullCalendar, so that it only executes once. Here is what you should put there - it's different to your code above because it fixes all the points 1-4 above:

```
var dt = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
var month_int = dt.month() + 1;
$(".fc-center").prepend('<label>' + month_int + '&nbsp;</label>');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/77/ for a demo of this.

Comment: how am i supposed to set month in the span from the view that you showed

Comment: you don't need to, that's the point. It's in the header already. Read my explanation again ("there is a better way to get the same effect") and look at the example in the link. There's already the month number there, neatly formatted, showing the correct month number, with no extra code or spans required.

Comment: ok thanks a lot, but how am i suppose to solve the problem with eventafterallrender, to not adding divs multiple times

Comment: the entire point of this being a "better" method is that you don't need that code any more, you can just remove it. Sorry, I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that the code shown here is intended to replace what you did, not add to it.

Comment: ok but I want to know in case I want to add somehting else, add it just once

Comment: in that case you'd have to just add it outside your calendar code, on the line after you declare fullCalendar, so that it doesn't run repeatedly. See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/77/ for an example, with other corrections according to the comments I made above. But the question asks quite specifically about the month, and what I provided is the answer to that. I will amend the answer to cover both scenarios.

Comment: thank you very mutch, so basically what i do is i append a div elements to the fc-center in full calendar , but when i change the view it doubles the div ,  but it should change the old div with the new one cause i have an input datepicker calendar that should show the selected month inside

Comment: I think you probably should give your div an ID and then when you want to change the content, you get that into a jQuery object, and over-write its contents using .html(). If you use .append() or prepend() it keeps adding more and more stuff. Check the jQuery docs for all the possible methods you can use, it'll help you understand the different possibilities: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/